# HTML Tables: How do I create a table of this form?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working with tables in HTML and I want to structure a table of the sorts that is shown in the image attached. The black borders are the gridlines and each letter represents an individual cell. Could anyone provide the code? Thanks!

[image: Table Structure]

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm this should be helpful to you.

Comment: Please do some googling before asking on SO. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 0):

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh. This was simple... :|